# Login and registration screen

Tags: angular, ng-zorro-antd

I have the following problem, I'm doing applications using ng-zorro-antd, and now I would like to do 2 components, one responsible for logging in, the other for registration. Unfortunately, the problem is that after creating these components, how to go after routing / login or / register then these 2 components use the main template and for example I have a sidebar. How can I make them not use any template? I would like the login and register to show only login and registration forms.

I have seen in many templates that as part of the BlankComponent write and it works, unfortunately it does not work with me.

My routes:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: DashboardComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'login',
    component: LoginComponent
  }
];
```

And now, as I write BlankComponent, for obvious reasons, it shows that there is no such component, if I enter the path itself, it also will not work because it will not be given what component should be loaded. If I enter LoginComponent, it will load the LoginComponent to me, but with this I will load the Sidebar which is in shared, and I want to get the effect that after entering the routing register I will see the same content RegisterComponent, without sidebar etc. with shared.

My AppComponent:

```
<nz-layout>
  <nz-sider [nzBreakpoint]="'lg'" [nzZeroTrigger]="zeroTrigger" nzCollapsible [(nzCollapsed)]="isCollapsed" [nzTrigger]="triggerTemplate"
    [nzWidth]="250" style="background-color: #000;">
    <div class="logo">
      <img src="../assets/logo.png" class="logo-img" />
    </div>
    <ul nz-menu [nzTheme]="'dark'" [nzMode]="'inline'" [nzInlineCollapsed]="isCollapsed">
      <li nz-submenu>
        <span title><i nz-icon type="money-collect" theme="outline"></i><span class="nav-text">Księgowość</span></span>
        <ul>
          <li nz-menu-item><i nz-icon type="right-circle" theme="outline"></i> Lista użytkowników</li>
          <li nz-menu-item><i nz-icon type="right-circle" theme="outline"></i> Lista transakcji</li>
          <li nz-menu-item><i nz-icon type="right-circle" theme="outline"></i> Lista dokumentów</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li nz-menu-item><span><i nz-icon type="setting" theme="outline"></i><span class="nav-text">Ustawienia</span></span></li>
    </ul>
  </nz-sider>
  <nz-layout style="height: 100%">
    <nz-header class="header">
      <i class="trigger" nz-icon [type]="isCollapsed?'menu-unfold':'menu-fold'" (click)="isCollapsed=!isCollapsed"></i>
      <nz-content class="profile">

        <nz-select class="language-select" nzPlaceHolder="Language">
          <nz-option nzLabel="Polski" nzValue="pl"></nz-option>
          <nz-option nzLabel="Angielski" nzValue="eng"></nz-option>
        </nz-select> 
      </nz-content>
    </nz-header>
    <nz-content style="margin:16px;">
      <div class="content">
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
      </div>
    </nz-content>
  </nz-layout>
</nz-layout>
<ng-template #trigger>
  <i nz-icon type="up"></i>
</ng-template>
<ng-template #zeroTrigger>
  <i nz-icon type="menu-fold" theme="outline"></i>
</ng-template>
```

And the problem is that after entering the RegisterComponent component all the content of the AppComponent appears to me, and I want to only read the contents of RegisterComponent

Comment: Can you show us your code? Read also How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I added the code :)